# organize facebook friends by categories

Tags: facebook

I use facebook to connect with friends from different countries,however, I want to organize them in categories or lists by country and see them when they are online. For example if I have 4 friends from UK, I will see them in the list of UK and know they are online... I'm sure there's a way out there, but I don't know how make it. can you help me please. my regards.

Note: I know facebook have friends lists feature, but I can not see who is online; I can only see posts published by friends in the friend list. I wonder if there is a third-party (ex: program, tool,..) that I can use in order to organize my friends by country and know when they are online.

I hope I make it clear for you to understand my point.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect if a friend is online on Facebook, there is no API for it. There is also no third party option, of course. Also, you can only get a list of friends who authorized your App too. You can't get a list of ALL friends anymore.